# No callback on channel laravel echo with VUE

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pusher, laravel-echo

I am stuck on the same point for the past two days. I tried all the possible solutions but had no success. Please check my below code and guide me where I am wrong.

**Error**

> Pusher :  : ["Event recd",{"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","channel":"private-chat","data":{}}]

> Pusher :  : ["No callbacks on private-chat for pusher:subscription_succeeded"]

**Event**

```
class NewMessageNotification implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Messages $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('chat');
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'messageSent';
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $message = new Messages;
        $message->to = $request->input('to');
        $message->from = $request->input('from');
        $message->message = $request->input('message');
        $message->save();

        broadcast(new NewMessageNotification($message));
    }
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo";

window.Pusher = require("pusher-js");

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: "pusher",
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true
});
Pusher.logToConsole = true;
```

**listener in vue file**

```
  created() {
        // this.getMessages();

        window.Echo.connector.pusher.connection.bind("connected", () => {
            console.log("connected");
        });

        window.Echo.private(`chat`).listen("messageSent", e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
    },
```

Comment: Share your routes/channels.php, you need to authenticate your private channels. I'm guessing you are getting unauthorised in console.

Comment: @AliRaza `Broadcast::channel('chat', function () {
    return auth()->check();
});
`

Comment: return TRUE for testing, also make sure process.env keys are resolving properly. Also for testing try hard coding pusher keys, and check if the issue is there.

Comment: As the client is receiving the `pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded` event they will be successfully subscribing to the channel. The error indicates that the client doesn't have a handler for receipt of this event. My solution below should suppress this.

Comment: @AliRaza no this is not working

Comment: can you see the event being fired in Pusher debug console.

Comment: No nothing happened in debug console.

Comment: It is working now, this was a cache issue. I just run `php artisan optimize` and it works

Answer (score 0):

This error shouldn't interfere with the subscription, but of course you wouldn't want it showing the in console. To stop this you can add a handler for the event as follows:

```
window.Echo.private(`chat`).listen("pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded", () => {
            console.log('Successfully subscribed to private-chat);
        });
```

Comment: I am also unable to listen to response from the pusher.